# SQL to handle potential for null result from subquery during insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am performing an insert, and using a subquery to select an email address for the insert statement, as such:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, date) 
VALUES (123,
        (SELECT email from list_of_emails 
         WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'),
        NOW())
```

The users table has a `non-null` constraint on an email address, so what I am trying to catch is the potential that there may not be an email address that matches the subquery, in which case a `not-null constraint` violation occurs.

Any suggestion on how to catch this value error during the subquery and return some error message like "email address was not found"

Comment: Use `INSERT ... SELECT 123, email, now() FROM email WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com';`  instead.  That will avoid attempting to insert if no email rows are found.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I'm using a default serial value to increment the id value, so I don't think I can use your suggestion?

Comment: It will work just fine with a serial column.  That has nothing to do with the question, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `INSERT ... SELECT ...;` form:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, date)
SELECT DISTINCT 123, email, now()
  FROM list_of_emails
 WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
;
```

This avoids attempting to insert when no email rows are found.  Hopefully, you don't have duplicate email entries, as that would have been a problem in the original as well.  I added a DISTINCT just in case, since I don't know your schema.  Remove the DISTINCT if email is guaranteed unique in the email table.

Comment: The id value is being auto generated, so I would expect to face a "DEFAULT is not allowed in this context" error when trying this.

Comment: @dataviews The id is a static literal in your question.  If it's autogenerated, just remove the id column from the INSERT and the SELECT.  If you have a question related to the autogenerated id, this is a different question.  Can you open a new question for that?

Comment: Thanks! didn't realize I was able to do that with an autogenerated field, I thought you still had to declare that column when inserting. Your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WHERE EXISTS.

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, date) VALUES (
123,
(
  SELECT email from list_of_emails WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com'
),
now() 
)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT email from list_of_emails WHERE email = 'abc@yahoo.com')
```